# Using methods of react components outside of react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a chat app and want to keep its parts separate.

For example, I have part of code where communication logic is described. So when somebody receives a message `addMessage` function can be used to pass it to react component:

```
import { addMessage } from './components/App.Chat.MessageField'

rtc.on('data', (data) => {
  /.../
  addMessage(message);
});
```

And `addMessaget` function is binded method of *react* component:

```
export var addMessage;

export default class MessageField extends Component {

  constructor() {
    /.../
    addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    /.../
  }

  addMessage(message) {
    /.../
    this.setState(/.../);
  }

}
```

So far, everything worked well. But I doubt that's good solution. **Can it cause some problems or is there any better ways to do it?**

Comment: Component methods are generally only supposed to be used by the component itself or possibly passed as props to child components. They should not be regarded as a public API. You could instead create a `rtc.on` listener in `componentDidMount` of the component, and remove the listener in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: @Tholle, thanks I'll try it. But I don't understand is this a bad practice only because of readability and conventions, or it can cause real mistakes in work of react app.

Comment: I don't think it will work, since each instance of the `MessageField` class will have a `addMessage` method bound to itself, so it's not clear which component's `addMessage` you will invoke by doing it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will lead to bugs. If you invoke `setState` on an unmounted component React will throw an error. In your example it means that if you are not in the case where `MessageField` is **never** unmounted then at some point `addMessage` will throw. Of course your app should not rely on any of your component never unmounting as it is a core part of the react's semantics.

A better way to do this could be to use `redux` and have the "add message" behaviour refactored around using redux state and actions. Your `rpc.on` snippet could be also put inside its own middleware.